# Effect version is unrecognized. This runtime supports fx_5_0 to fx_5_0

Tags: directx11, lighting, c++

I'm reading the "Introduction to 3D game programming with DirectX11" (Frank Luna) and i'm having problems with lighting.
I have this error: Effect version is unrecognized.  This runtime supports fx_5_0 to fx_5_0. 
When i use the D3DX11CreateEffectFromMemory function i have that error and an exception (this->mFX was nullptr)
Can you help me? Thanks
EDIT: I have no D3DCompileFromFile

```
std::ifstream fin("Ligthing.fx", std::ios::binary);  
        ///
        fin.seekg(0, std::ios_base::end);
        int size = (int)fin.tellg();
        fin.seekg(0, std::ios_base::beg);
        std::vector<char> compiledShader(size);

        fin.read(&compiledShader[0], size);
        fin.close();
        hr=D3DX11CreateEffectFromMemory(&compiledShader[0], size, //ERROR IS HERE
            0, device, &mFX);

        if (FAILED(hr)) {
            MessageBox(0, L"err", 0, 0);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the latest version of *Effects for Direct3D 11* which is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/FX11). It includes `D3DX11CreateEffectFromFile` which is for creating an effect from a compiled effect file (aka `fxo`), and `D3DX11CompileEffectFromFile` which is for creating an effect from a shader that is first compiled at runtime (aka `fx`).

> See [this post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2012/10/23/effects-for-direct3d-11-update/) for some history of Effects for Direct3D 11

The older version of Effects for Direct3D 11 in the [legacy DirectX SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663275.aspx) was a bit purist about forcing the developer to deal with the binary file loading and interop with [D3DCompile](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2012/05/07/hlsl-fxc-and-d3dcompile/). I just added the missing utility functions to the library instead when I moved it to GitHub.

> Be sure to read [Is Effects 11 deprecated?](https://fx11.codeplex.com/discussions/450240) and [What's the difference between an .fx and .hlsl file anyhow?](https://fx11.codeplex.com/discussions/551307) as well for the status of FX11.

Comment: Thanks for the help, i have the latest version of Effects already and my code is working, but i didn't know about the .fxo thing, so thank you a lot

Answer (score -1):

So the problem was in the "Lighting.fx". Had to compile it, so it became "Lighting.fxo". I didn't compile it by myself, i used the one provided by the book i'm reading which is "Intruduction to 3d game porgramming with DirectX 11" (Frank Luna)